# Query no longer working after upgrading to solr 7 from solr 4 (Occur Should vs Occur Must in edismax)

Tags: solr

I have a query that looks like this:
http://localhost:8984/solr/UT990001/select?defType=edismax&q=Red+Blue+%2BBlack+-White&qf=cfs_U3RyaW5nQ0Y_3

My expectation is that the query will return only if the field `cfs_U3RyaW5nQ0Y_3` contains 'Black' and does not contain White. If the values Red and Blue are present they would occur higher in the search results.

This is no longer working on my Solr 7 configuration.
I have 2 setups (Solr 4 & Solr 7) with the same data in each.
When I run the above query in Solr 4 it works as expected, however in Solr 7 zero results are returned.

Here is an idea of what I have seeded for data, values = the value of `cfs_U3RyaW5nQ0Y_3`

- Doc1 = Red
- Doc2 = Red
- Doc3 = Black
- Doc4 = Black
- Doc5 = White
- Doc6 = Blue
- Doc7 = Red Black White Blue
- Doc8 = Back and White

Results:

- Solr4: 2 hits, Doc3 and Doc4
- Solr7: 0 hits

Any insights on where to start looking are appreciated.

We alias fields (user doesn't search for `cfs_U3RyaW5nQ0Y_3` but rather `color` (I have boiled down the url used to search to the above to simplify)

The field `cfs_U3RyaW5nQ0Y_3` type is defined as:

```
<fieldType name="text_auto" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5" EclipseRevision="38447">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.IntPointField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongPointField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.DoublePointField" omitNorms="true" />
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.DoublePointField" omitNorms="true" />
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.DatePointField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="text_auto" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="string_sorted" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>           
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>    
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="type" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="title" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="keywords" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="created" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="modified" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="securityclassid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="contenttypeid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="extension" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="nonindexedmeta" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
    <!--Dumping ground for items we want included in search results but do not want search hits on; see NonIndexedMeta class -->
    <dynamicField name="cfi_*" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="cfs_*"  type="text_auto"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <!-- Do not make cfg_* into a text_auto -->
    <dynamicField name="cfg_*"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="cfl_*"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="cfb_*"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="cfbd_*"  type="double"  indexed="false"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="cfdt_*"  type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="cfdo_*"  type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="qcfbd_*"  type="tdouble"  indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
    <!-- The following are used for sorting only. -->
    <!-- Do not make any sorted field text_auto #13895 -->
    <field name="title_sort" type="string_sorted" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="keywords_sort" type="string_sorted" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="scfi_*" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="scfs_*"  type="string_sorted"  indexed="true"  stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="scfg_*"  type="string_sorted"  indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="scfl_*"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="scfb_*"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="scfbd_*"  type="double"  indexed="true"  stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="scfdt_*"  type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="scfdo_*"  type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="false" />
    <!-- This field is used to build the spellchecker index -->
    <field name="typeahead" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
  </fields>
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_sort"/>
  <copyField source="keywords" dest="keywords_sort"/>
  <copyField source="title" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="keywords" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="cfi_*" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="cfs_*" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="cfl_*" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="cfb_*" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="cfbd_*" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="cfdt_*" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="cfdo_*" dest="typeahead"/>
  <copyField source="scfbd_*" dest="qcfbd_*"/>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Comment: Can you share your schema?

Comment: I've tested your documents with a fresh collection on 7.2 with both your included field type and the default `text_en` field type, and both produce the result you're looking for. Do you have the `luceneMatchVersion` set to a specific version?

Comment: Added the Schema

Comment: <luceneMatchVersion>7.1.0</luceneMatchVersion>

Comment: Updated to 7.4 and I have the same behavior.